# Python: Shell with grep value stored in variable appends always a additional line

Tags: python, shell, grep, subprocess

I forgot add, I must call shell from python, 
I have a file

```
cat file.txt
b
bb
bbb
```

Print if only "bb" exists else fail,

```
str=subprocess.check_output('grep bb file.txt || echo 2',shell=True)
print 'str='+str  # This always str=bb and an extra line
if (str == 'bb'):   # Wish  better way like str == '1'
  print "Pass"
elif(str == '2') :
  print "Fail"
```

I think there should be a better way to handle.

Comment: Can you try adding `--quiet` to your grep invocation? That should suppress grep’s printing of matching lines.

Comment: This is a really suboptimal way of solving the problem. Try to use Python, rather than shelling out to grep.

Comment: -q (quiet) suppres all std output (infact mine is multistaged grep shell command tobe invoked from python)

Comment: @Krishna : Your `grep` tests whether the line **contains** two successive `b`. Hence it also matches `bbb`. To find lines which consist of only `bb` and nothing else, `grep -Fx bb` would do the job. But as several others have pointed out already, it is pointless to invoke a child process for this task, when you can do it easily within Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the file and reading it either line by line or as a whole:

- As a whole

```py
    with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
        data = file.read()
        if "bbb" in data:
            print("Pass")
        else:
            print("Fail")
```

- Or line by line

```py
    with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
        line = file.readline()
        while line:
            if "bbb" == line:
                print("Pass")
                break
            line = file.readline()
        print("Fail")
```

EDIT:  I saw you edited your question. The if statement can change and it wont affect the program so it doesn't matter what you check for(e.g. 'bbb' or '11'). Also checking line by line is a better and faster option.

Comment: Thanks, actually my command is multistaged grep and invoking from python, (I just put a sample code there), Is there anyway to suppress addiotional trailing line, hence want to avoid multiline of checking the str value.

Comment: Can I read 'str' itself as a stream of characters (like file) ?

Comment: You want to read every character of the string that `line` returns?

Comment: Yes, I am focusing on 'str' as in real case I might get multiple occurances line of the pattern (say 'bbb' , 'bbbbb' etc)

Comment: The way you check if that string is in a line does what you're saying you want to do. It checks if "bbb" is exactly equal to that line. Is there a reason you want to check how many characters a string has?